# How do I pass state to components when using a `react-router` config

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using a route config as defined [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config). But, when using this method of router configuration how do I pass props to the components?

Looking at the following method from the docs there doesn't seem to be a way to provide props:

```
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
  <Route path={route.path} render={props => (
    // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
    <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
  )}/>
)
```

Doing something like the following doesn't work. The prop doesn't get passed through:

```
{routes.map((route, i) => (
    <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} user={this.state.user} {...route}/>
))}
```

I am using React's default state management. Do I need Redux for this?

Comment: You would need to use Redux for this as you would need to pass the store component to the app to have access to all of your required components.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how to use Flux + React together to pass props. I hope this is useful for you. Let me know if you have other questions.

**AppComponent.js**

In your AppComponent, you would need to pass only the pages you need to render.

```
render () {
     <div>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path= "/:date?" component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
}
```

In your **app.js** component, you import all services, actions, and main store component you need. Checkout bottle.js for easier way to pass values and services. However, you would need to just render

```
ReactDOM.render(
    (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Route path="/" AppStore={AppStore} render={props => <AppComponent {...props} AppStore={AppStore} />} />
        </BrowserRouter>
    ),
    document.getElementById("view-container")
);
```

You should let the parent component like the component Dashboard in AppComponment.js get the data passed from app.js to AppComponent to Dashboard (and Dashboard's children components).

As for AppStore, this would be like a container for all your other stores. You would need import all your other data store components and actions.